# Overlapping Confidence Interval Alphas in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha, confidence-interval

I'm trying to visualize the confidence intervals for a set of Monte Carlo draws and am having some issues with my approach using alpha levels.

I'm running a loess regression for each draw and I wanted to try to visualize how the confidence intervals from each draw overlapped by displaying them on top of one another with reduced alphas to produce a gradient effect.
Essentially in the end produce the darkest areas would show where the confidence intervals overlapped the most.

As you can see in the example, the central portions are heavily obscured. While this pattern is to be expected, there isn't as much differentiation shown in the central portions as I need. I tried reducing the alpha level, but the result remained the same.  <s>After some looking around I found that ggplot2 doesn't display alphas at levels lower than 0.1.</s>

**Edit**
*As mentioned in the comment, the alpha can in fact be set below 0.1, and from my own quick testing it seems anything set at 0.005 is where it fails to display. Even though this is quite low, I would like to display the alpha at an even lower level or use an alternative approach if possible.*

The included sample set is a little long, but in the initial 20 draw sample the problem wasn't as clear. This set shown here includes 50 draws, but the actual analysis consists of 1000 draws, so the effect is even more pronounced.

I'd like to know if there are any workaround to achieve an effect that is similar to what I'm looking for, or if there is another way to visualize this.

Sample plot image set at 0.1
[image: Overlapping confidence interval alphas from 50 draws- alpha 0.1]

Sample plot image set at 0.006
[image: Overlapping confidence interval alphas from 50 draws - alpha 0.006]

Sample code

```
ggplot(data = subset(play, !is.na(y)), 
       aes(x = -x, y = y, group = RunID)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", linetype = 0, alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  theme_minimal()
```

Reproducible sample

```
dput(play)
structure(list(x = c(-4616, -4510, -4465, -4473, -4466, -4689, 
-5301, -5214, -4880, -4869, -5122, -4771, -5045, -4535, -4670, 
-4988, -4752, -4478, -4427, -4650, -5284, -4866, -4930, -4915, 
-5136, -4599, -5246, -4806, -4554, -5046, -4429, -4419, -4494, 
-4631, -4403, -5309, -5197, -4900, -4889, -5107, -5131, -4410, 
-4635, -4558, -4912, -5010, -5330, -4484, -4669, -4665, -4541, 
-4420, -5295, -4901, -4867, -4911, -5170, -4496, -5068, -4401, 
-4680, -4810, -4528, -4980, -4487, -4626, -4649, -4456, -5296, 
-5087, -4945, -4883, -5201, -5302, -4436, -4654, -4609, -5052, 
-4909, -4485, -4531, -4423, -4609, -5280, -5091, -4901, -4862, 
-5216, -4829, -4806, -4809, -4776, -4729, -5386, -4412, -4571, 
-4595, -4410, -4475, -5302, -5010, -4891, -4867, -5217, -4870, 
-4417, -4838, -4582, -4696, -5035, -5346, -4488, -4589, -4430, 
-5275, -5150, -4878, -4929, -5118, -5284, -4968, -4737, -4877, 
-5159, -4963, -4469, -4624, -4473, -4431, -5282, -5268, -4924, 
-4928, -5228, -4891, -4923, -4643, -4550, -4848, -4878, -4451, 
-4547, -4470, -4466, -4446, -5304, -5085, -4885, -4868, -5104, 
-4742, -4703, -4586, -4930, -4747, -5226, -4550, -4448, -5290, 
-4892, -4936, -4929, -5138, -5143, -4520, -4490, -4910, -4914, 
-4505, -4574, -4540, -4476, -4500, -4645, -4462, -5306, -4924, 
-4898, -4888, -5217, -5283, -4462, -4719, -4881, -4740, -4497, 
-5234, -5111, -4461, -4413, -4480, -4566, -4552, -4424, -5303, 
-4964, -4878, -4881, -5160, -4449, -4566, -4702, -4737, -4463, 
-5070, -4422, -4457, -4452, -4681, -4578, -5271, -4873, -4887, 
-4889, -5185, -4985, -4514, -4924, -4573, -4540, -5168, -4475, 
-4594, -4662, -5299, -4990, -4869, -4923, -4435, -5170, -4488, 
-4623, -4596, -4532, -4651, -4435, -4414, -4550, -4702, -4405, 
-5283, -5267, -4927, -4915, -5193, -5177, -4959, -4647, -4569, 
-4722, -5316, -4424, -4486, -4402, -4672, -4494, -5291, -5134, 
-4883, -4950, -5125, -4814, -4405, -4674, -4729, -4668, -5244, 
-5348, -4405, -4507, -4612, -4632, -4460, -5299, -4995, -4861, 
-4944, -5171, -5220, -4906, -4875, -4766, -4709, -5213, -5085, 
-4455, -4402, -4715, -4729, -4435, -4415, -5271, -5266, -4915, 
-4919, -5148, -5324, -4706, -4824, -4847, -4786, -4425, -4447, 
-4644, -4549, -4632, -5281, -5012, -4923, -4947, -5140, -5202, 
-5188, -4747, -4642, -4633, -4689, -4433, -4474, -4616, -4462, 
-4468, -5297, -5293, -4941, -4920, -5125, -4406, -5352, -4844, 
-4590, -4423, -4456, -4436, -4675, -4507, -5297, -4867, -4900, 
-4902, -4436, -5141, -4603, -4849, -4932, -4669, -4493, -4544, 
-4434, -4490, -4409, -4590, -4418, -4698, -4471, -5288, -5309, 
-4935, -4912, -5172, -4973, -4806, -4540, -4616, -4847, -5223, 
-4449, -4481, -4541, -4617, -5301, -5177, -4938, -4893, -5179, 
-5124, -4668, -4635, -4432, -4739, -4945, -4901, -4432, -4475, 
-4661, -4503, -4442, -5309, -5271, -4941, -4925, -5204, -5242, 
-5086, -4828, -4543, -5020, -5359, -4404, -4475, -4659, -4689, 
-5276, -5241, -4944, -4862, -5119, -5286, -4403, -4517, -4610, 
-4869, -4717, -5017, -4479, -4438, -4450, -4730, -4607, -4467, 
-4453, -5307, -5157, -4884, -4861, -5213, -4444, -4675, -4886, 
-4473, -4786, -5311, -4724, -4411, -4655, -4418, -4440, -5282, 
-4875, -4909, -4872, -5193, -5242, -4909, -4565, -4615, -4881, 
-5114, -4419, -4663, -4471, -5300, -5097, -4880, -4879, -5100, 
-4610, -4428, -4618, -4922, -4778, -4907, -4403, -4605, -4585, 
-4431, -5275, -5032, -4875, -4933, -5125, -5264, -4596, -4768, 
-4630, -4550, -4444, -4415, -4495, -4685, -4433, -4481, -4423, 
-5274, -5199, -4869, -4861, -5166, -5225, -5068, -4468, -4743, 
-4586, -4936, -5319, -4873, -4422, -4471, -4705, -4589, -4428, 
-5307, -4898, -4897, -4891, -5121, -4837, -4501, -4786, -4946, 
-5253, -5061, -4421, -4717, -4528, -4448, -5291, -5062, -4897, 
-4914, -5181, -5399, -4453, -5250, -4838, -4629, -4716, -4551, 
-4689, -4425, -4467, -4592, -4401, -4427, -5270, -4984, -4867, 
-4879, -5222, -4467, -4922, -4480, -4723, -4621, -4827, -4525, 
-4538, -4586, -4426, -4463, -5285, -5096, -4895, -4890, -5200, 
-4844, -4432, -4752, -4726, -5195, -5108, -4410, -4454, -4596, 
-4475, -5279, -5014, -4939, -4942, -5210, -5357, -4795, -4580, 
-4792, -4535, -4756, -5312, -4437, -4451, -4709, -4547, -4463, 
-5286, -5217, -4877, -4905, -5185, -4984, -4532, -4809, -4492, 
-4878, -4657, -4719, -4443, -4472, -4663, -4666, -4528, -5307, 
-5115, -4940, -4932, -5148, -4837, -4479, -4901, -4538, -5017, 
-4730, -4464, -4518, -4405, -4589, -5292, -5063, -4934, -4943, 
-5168, -5219, -4509, -4774, -4460, -4809, -4843, -4740, -4426, 
-4538, -4710, -4573, -4567, -4470, -4402, -5270, -5256, -4901, 
-4916, -5196, -5326, -4855, -4726, -4558, -4458, -4448, -4539, 
-4567, -4594, -4552, -5294, -4917, -4863, -4891, -5189, -4786, 
-5329, -4669, -4680, -5302, -5285, -4459, -4472, -4673, -4720, 
-5307, -4864, -4929, -4906, -5219, -5088, -5031, -4491, -4552, 
-4560, -5187, -4497, -4649, -4466, -4715, -4444, -5270, -4999, 
-4939, -4897, -5106, -4798, -4890, -4583, -4841, -4517, -4858, 
-4484, -4432, -4714, -4447, -5300, -4876, -4932, -4949, -4428, 
-5187, -4754, -5293, -4806, -4740, -4993, -4440, -4419, -4436, 
-4682, -4648, -4609, -5290, -5128, -4862, -4861, -5105, -5181, 
-4488, -4981, -4510, -4694, -5064, -4456, -4448, -4639, -4485, 
-4537, -5299, -4975, -4943, -4865, -5190, -4628, -4921, -4552, 
-4665, -4863, -4592, -4544, -4425, -4471, -4728, -4511, -5296, 
-5284, -4928, -4863, -5172, -5069, -4970, -4803, -4722, -4852, 
-4827, -5333, -4438, -4514, -4489, -4575, -4402, -4541, -5282, 
-5031, -4908, -4928, -5161, -5370, -4453, -5381, -4694, -4578, 
-4479, -4733, -4473, -4407, -4552, -4444, -4596, -4424, -5295, 
-5114, -4933, -4915, -5156, -5385, -5106, -4713, -4692, -5305, 
-5095, -4482, -4706, -4654, -4440, -5292, -5267, -4912, -4946, 
-5114, -5295, -4542, -4543, -4745), y = c(0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.126984126984127, 0.2, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.133333333333333, 
0.126984126984127, 0.2, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 
0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 
0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0, 0.2, 0.193548387096774, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 
0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.133333333333333, 
0.160493827160494, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.2, 0.184027777777778, 
0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.125, 
0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.126984126984127, 0.2, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 
0.133333333333333, 0.160493827160494, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 
0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.193548387096774, 
0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.160493827160494, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 
0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.160493827160494, 
0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.133333333333333, 0.160493827160494, 
0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.2, 0.133333333333333, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.2, 0.184027777777778, 
0.130434782608696, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 
0.2, 0.160493827160494, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.193548387096774, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.130434782608696, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.126984126984127, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 
0.125, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.126984126984127, 0.2, 0.133333333333333, 
0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.130434782608696, 
0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0.4, 0.2, 0.133333333333333, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0.22884012539185, 
0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.133333333333333, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 
0.126984126984127, 0.2, 0.133333333333333, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.193548387096774, 
0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.2, 0.133333333333333, 0.125, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.130434782608696, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.133333333333333, 
0.160493827160494, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 
0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.133333333333333, 
0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.2, 0.160493827160494, 0, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 
0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0.22884012539185, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 
0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.126984126984127, 
0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.133333333333333, 0.160493827160494, 
0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.126984126984127, 0.2, 0.133333333333333, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.130434782608696, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.160493827160494, 
0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.193548387096774, 
0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.126984126984127, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 
0.133333333333333, 0, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 
0.130434782608696, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 
0.125, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.2, 0, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.160493827160494, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 
0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.160493827160494, 0.125, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.2, 0.184027777777778, 0.130434782608696, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.126984126984127, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.133333333333333, 
0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0, 0.2, 0.184027777777778, 0.130434782608696, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.125, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 
0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.193548387096774, 
0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.130434782608696, 0.5, 
0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.126984126984127, 0.2, 0.133333333333333, 
0.160493827160494, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.2, 0.184027777777778, 
0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.133333333333333, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 
0.160493827160494, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 
0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.2, 0.160493827160494, 
0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.130434782608696, 
0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.126984126984127, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 
0.133333333333333, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 
0.130434782608696, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.126984126984127, 
0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.133333333333333, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 
0.126984126984127, 0.2, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 
0.130434782608696, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 
0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.133333333333333, 0.125, 0, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 
0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.133333333333333, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 
0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 
0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.133333333333333, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 
0.133333333333333, 0.160493827160494, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 
0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 
0.2, 0.160493827160494, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0.22884012539185, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 
0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.133333333333333, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.193548387096774, 
0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.133333333333333, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.130434782608696, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.241803278688029, 
0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.130434782608696, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.126984126984127, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 
0.133333333333333, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.193548387096774, 0.166666666666667, 
0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 0, 0.4, 0.126984126984127, 
0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0.133333333333333, 0.160493827160494, 
0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 0.244791666666667, 
0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 0.5, 0.191919191919192, 
0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.296296296296296, 0, 0.241803278688029, 0.2, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.244791666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.184027777777778, 
0.5), RunID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 
46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 
49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 
50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
50L)), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
    28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
    40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
    52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
    64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
    76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 
    88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 
    100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 
    110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 
    120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 
    130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 
    140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 
    150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 
    160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 
    170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 
    180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 
    190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 
    200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 
    210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 
    220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 
    230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 
    240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 
    250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 
    260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 
    270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 
    280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 
    290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 
    300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 
    310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 
    320L, 321L, 322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 
    330L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 
    340L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 
    350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 
    360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 
    370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 377L, 378L, 379L, 
    380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 386L, 387L, 388L, 389L, 
    390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 396L, 397L, 398L, 399L, 
    400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 
    410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 
    420L, 421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 
    430L, 431L, 432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 
    440L, 441L, 442L, 443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 
    450L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 
    460L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 464L, 465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 
    470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 474L, 475L, 476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 
    480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 486L, 487L, 488L, 489L, 
    490L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 499L, 
    500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 508L, 509L, 
    510L, 511L, 512L, 513L, 514L, 515L, 516L, 517L, 518L, 519L, 
    520L, 521L, 522L, 523L, 524L, 525L, 526L, 527L, 528L, 529L, 
    530L, 531L, 532L, 533L, 534L, 535L, 536L, 537L, 538L, 539L, 
    540L, 541L, 542L, 543L, 544L, 545L, 546L, 547L, 548L, 549L, 
    550L, 551L, 552L, 553L, 554L, 555L, 556L, 557L, 558L, 559L, 
    560L, 561L, 562L, 563L, 564L, 565L, 566L, 567L, 568L, 569L, 
    570L, 571L, 572L, 573L, 574L, 575L, 576L, 577L, 578L, 579L, 
    580L, 581L, 582L, 583L, 584L, 585L, 586L, 587L, 588L, 589L, 
    590L, 591L, 592L, 593L, 594L, 595L, 596L, 597L, 598L, 599L, 
    600L, 601L, 602L, 603L, 604L, 605L, 606L, 607L, 608L, 609L, 
    610L, 611L, 612L, 613L, 614L, 615L, 616L, 617L, 618L, 619L, 
    620L, 621L, 622L, 623L, 624L, 625L, 626L, 627L, 628L, 629L, 
    630L, 631L, 632L, 633L, 634L, 635L, 636L, 637L, 638L, 639L, 
    640L, 641L, 642L, 643L, 644L, 645L, 646L, 647L, 648L, 649L, 
    650L, 651L, 652L, 653L, 654L, 655L, 656L, 657L, 658L, 659L, 
    660L, 661L, 662L, 663L, 664L, 665L, 666L, 667L, 668L, 669L, 
    670L, 671L, 672L, 673L, 674L, 675L, 676L, 677L, 678L, 679L, 
    680L, 681L, 682L, 683L, 684L, 685L, 686L, 687L, 688L, 689L, 
    690L, 691L, 692L, 693L, 694L, 695L, 696L, 697L, 698L, 699L, 
    700L, 701L, 702L, 703L, 704L, 705L, 706L, 707L, 708L, 709L, 
    710L, 711L, 712L, 713L, 714L, 715L, 716L, 717L, 718L, 719L, 
    720L, 721L, 722L, 723L, 724L, 725L, 726L, 727L, 728L, 729L, 
    730L, 731L, 732L, 733L, 734L, 735L, 736L, 737L, 738L, 739L, 
    740L, 741L, 742L, 743L, 744L, 745L, 746L, 747L, 748L, 749L, 
    750L, 751L, 752L, 753L, 754L, 755L, 756L, 757L, 758L, 759L, 
    760L, 761L, 762L, 763L, 764L, 765L, 766L, 767L, 768L, 769L, 
    770L, 771L, 772L, 773L, 774L, 775L, 776L, 777L, 778L, 779L, 
    780L, 781L, 782L, 783L, 784L, 785L, 786L, 787L, 788L, 789L, 
    790L, 791L, 792L, 793L, 794L, 795L, 796L, 797L, 798L, 799L, 
    800L, 801L, 802L, 803L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -803L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, -803L), class = c("rowwise_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot2` *does* recognise `alpha` values less than 0.1.

For example:

```r
ggplot(data = subset(play, !is.na(y)), aes(x = -x, y = y, group = RunID)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "loess", linetype = 0, alpha = 0.01) +
    scale_x_reverse() +
    theme_minimal()
```

produces

[image]

Only when you use an alpha transparency *scale* through an aesthetic, values are mapped to alpha values in the interval [0.1, 1].

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and you're absolutely right. Turns out the cutoff seems to be anything set at 0.005 or lower. I am still in the situation where I am looking to display it at lower alpha levels however and would appreciate any ideas or workarounds. Thanks!

Comment: No worries @Corey. TBH I am a bit unclear as to what you're expecting as output. You're saying that you're after something where "[...] the darkest areas would show where the confidence intervals overlapped the most". This is exactly what the previous plots at any of the alpha values show. Increasing opacity won't change this. Is it possible for you to show a mock-up (perhaps using Illustrator) of how you expect your output plot to look?

Comment: [continued] I've got a feeling this might be a bit of an XY problem. I found the functions & visualisations discussed [here](http://mjskay.github.io/tidybayes/) very useful. For example, you can show draws from the posterior means or from the posterior predictive distribution.

Comment: The fit curves example from the tidybayes package is similar to the effect I was looking to cheat with the alphas. While the alphas show a difference between the lighter outer portions and the darker inner portions, I was really hoping for an additional step of resolution. Without being able to lower the alpha further I'm unable to tell if the solid color boundary is more representative of the "minimum" range of the confidence intervals or a display limitation. I might be pushing the alpha angle as far as it can go however and it could be helpful to take a different approach to the analysis.